# Poincaré type inequality Lipschitz function

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume that $\Omega$ is a bounded set, $\mu$ is a finite measure and $f$ is a Lipschitz function with constant $1$.
Suppose that
$$\int_\Omega f(s)\ d\mu(s)=0$$
is it true that
$$\int_\Omega f(s)^2\ d\mu(s)\le C = C\|f\|_L$$

where $C$ is a constant depending only on $\Omega$?

The reason why I pose this question is that it is similar to one formulation of the classical Poincaré inequality:

$$\int_\Omega f(s)\ ds=0,\ f\in H^1(\Omega)\implies \int_\Omega f(s)^2\ ds\le C \int_\Omega |\nabla f(s)|^2\ ds$$

where we generalize to any measure $\mu$ (instead of the Lebesgue one) and therefore we ask the function to be Lipschitz instead of in $H^1(\Omega)$ (any response with $f\in H^1$ would be also welcome btw)

Comment: What is your definition of $\|f\|_L$?

Comment: It's $\sup_{x,y} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}$ (tecnically it is not a norm, but a semi-norm)

Answer (score 1):

In case there is a  point $x_0 \in \Omega$ with $f(x_0) = 0$, for any other point $s \in \Omega$ you have $$f(s)^2 = |f(s)||f(s) - f(x_0)| \le |f(s)||s - x_0| \le \|f\|_\infty \cdot\mathrm{diam\ }\Omega$$ so that $$\int_\Omega f(s)^2 \, d\mu(s) \le \mu(\Omega) \mathrm{diam\ }\Omega\|f\|_\infty.$$ You can finish the inequality in terms of the Lipschitz norm of $f$.

What if $f$ doesn't vanish anywhere on $\Omega$? That will give you some information about the measure $\mu$ that you can use.

Comment: But with the condition of the null integral isn't there a way to do the same without $x_0$?

Comment: That was the question I posed on the last line.